# Is it possible to produce a sound from frequency spectrum data?

Tags: javascript, fft, web-audio-api

With an AnalyzerNode, you can convert a sound into frequency spectrum data with the [getByteFrequencyData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteFrequencyData) / [getFloatFrequencyData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getFloatFrequencyData) methods.

Is it possible to go in the reverse direction, and play a sound from frequency spectrum data?

Comment: I'm guessing no, since there are no `set` functions for frequency data.

Comment: However, you could take some frequency data and perform an inverse FFT on it yourself to get a waveform and play that.

Comment: Yes you can. See here: http://marcgg.com/blog/2016/11/01/javascript-audio/

Comment: @Dai That's not what he was asking about.

Comment: @Herohtar the article describes sound synthesis from single sinusoidal waveforms. It is not a direct solution to the OP’s problem but with the OP’s frequency spectrum data it’s just a matter of extending this technique for each frequency revealed by FFT.

Answer (score 0):

The frequency spectrum data must include the phase information.  If it does, you can use the `OscillatorNode` to reproduce the periodic sound.  Convert the magnitude and phase information (polar form) to the real and imaginary (rectangular) components to create an appropriate `PeriodicWave` and initialize an `OscillatorNode` with that periodic wave.

The information from an `AnalyserNode` is not enough because that only contains the magnitude part of the frequency spectrum.